# pdo invalid number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO test(emailAddress, password) VALUES(:emailAddress, :password)");
$data = array("emailAddress" => "test1", "password" => "test", "abc" => 123);

if($statement->execute($data)) {
    echo $connection->lastInsertId();
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

I know the number of tokens are more than the required, but sometimes my array could have more and I need them.

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'
```

Can PDO ignore extra parameters?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you need to do this? It seems faster just to comment out that bit...

Comment: because you have an extra "abc"=>123 in the array? try removing it

Comment: my array is carrying some parameters from previous transactions as well as for more down the road.

Comment: @craftein can't do that, I've pasted a small test isolated case here, and I need those extra params in, can we suggest PDO to ignore extra params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PDO requires that you have the same number of values as the number of parameters in the prepared query.

Learn to use [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$keys = array("emailAddress", "password");
$data = array("emailAddress" => "test1", "password" => "test", "abc" => 123);

if($statement->execute(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keys)))) {
    . . .
```

Comment: Heh, that's pretty nifty. I'll have to remember this one.

Comment: Thanks Bill (with the exception that function name is array_intersect_key)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I have fixed it above.